# Find a property of an object in array of objects with the min/max number in another property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I have `notes` that have a `lastEdit` which is a timestamp in milliseconds and a unique `id`. I want to find the `id` of the note that has the greatest `lastEdit` value.

I tried the good old fashion way, and then figured there must be an es6 way of doing this, but even after a lot of struggling and getting it to work, it's even messier.

I'm wondering if there's a cleaner / better way of doing this. I don't care about ties in timestamp or performance much. Here's what I got so far:

```js
const getMostRecentNote = () => {
    let maxTimestamp = 0;
    let maxId = -1;
    notes.forEach((n) => {
        if (maxTimestamp < n.lastEdit) {
            maxTimestamp = n.lastEdit;
            maxId = n.id;
        }
    });

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/43576363/4907950
    const rtn = notes.reduce((acc, note) => {
        if (acc.maxTimestamp === undefined) {
            acc = { maxTimestamp: -1, maxId: -1 };
        }
        if (note.lastEdit > acc.maxTimestamp) {
            acc = { maxTimestamp: note.lastEdit, maxId: note.id };
        }
        return acc;
    }, {}).maxId;

    return [maxId, rtn];
};
```

Update: realized I can just logical or the reduce one:

```js
const rtn = notes.reduce((acc, note) => {
        if (
            acc.maxTimestamp === undefined ||
            note.lastEdit > acc.maxTimestamp
        ) {
            acc = { maxTimestamp: note.lastEdit, maxId: note.id };
        }
        return acc;
    }, {}).maxId;
```

I still like the simple version better but let me know what you think or if you can think of something simpler : )

Update 2:
Even simpler:

```js
    const rtn = notes.reduce(
        (acc, note) =>
            acc.maxTimestamp === undefined || note.lastEdit > acc.maxTimestamp
                ? { maxTimestamp: note.lastEdit, maxId: note.id }
                : acc,
        {}
    ).maxId;
```

or:

```js
    const rtn = notes.reduce(
        (acc, note) =>
            note.lastEdit > acc.maxTimestamp
                ? { maxTimestamp: note.lastEdit, maxId: note.id }
                : acc,
        { maxTimestamp: -1 }
    ).maxId;
```

Comment: Maybe a custom `sort` function on the array to sort by timestamp? would be aO(nlogn) for a O(n) problem though

Comment: Would `return notes.sort((a, b) => b.lastEdit - a.lastEdit)[0].id;` be considered bad code?

Comment: I should add for my use case the `sort` way runs seemingly instantly with 250 items, which is the max I allow my users (could change)

Comment: Also `sort` mutates the original object, but that's fine in this case. Worth noting for others viewing this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

A short review;

First a meta remark; providing 4 versions isn't really in the spirit of CodeReview ;)

- Since it seems to return the id instead of the note, you probabably want to call the function `getMostRecentNoteId` or really return the note
- `sort` would help, but changes `notes`, since we only care about `id` and `lastEdit` we could create a new list with just those values
- Not a big fan of `rtn`, I am a big fan of spelled out words or Spartan variables, how about `out`?
- I am a big fan of the `function` keyword, it's more readable to me
- `notes` seems to be a global, that is definitely not best practice

Mandatory counter-proposal;

```
function getMostRecentNoteInfo(notes){

  const bareNotes = notes.map(o=>[o.maxId, o.maxTimestamp]);
  return bareNotes.sort((a, b) => a.lastEdit - b.lastEdit).pop();

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth reply. I agree with most of your feedback and appreciate the function you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions are complicated.

---

A simpler solution.

```
// mostRecentNote returns the id of the note 
// with the most recent lastEdit timestamp.
function mostRecentNote(notes) {
    return notes.reduce((prev, curr) => { 
            return (prev.lastEdit > curr.lastEdit) ? prev : curr;
        }, 
        [],
    ).id;
}
```

Comment: Nice, this is quite clean and readable imo!